# Return sunrise and sunset time based on a datetime using Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

My `df` is like this.

```
DateTime            Pdc
01/04/2016 10:00    1
01/04/2016 10:05    2
02/04/2016 10:10    3
02/04/2016 10:15    4
03/04/2016 10:20    5
03/04/2016 10:25    6
03/04/2016 10:30    7
```

I want to add two columns of sunrise time and sunset time based on the **date** on the `df` like below as an example:

```
DateTime            Pdc  Sunrise  Sunset
01/04/2016 10:00    1    time     time
01/04/2016 10:05    2    time     time
02/04/2016 10:10    3    time     time
02/04/2016 10:15    4    time     time
03/04/2016 10:20    5    time     time
03/04/2016 10:25    6    time     time
03/04/2016 10:30    7    time     time
```

I have no idea how to do that. Trying [this](https://michelanders.blogspot.com/2010/12/calulating-sunrise-and-sunset-in-python.html), I don't know how to implement it without package `timezone`. [This](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/almanac.html#sunrise-and-sunset) return error that I cannot solve. [This](https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/) works with Python 2, I didn't check it. [This](https://pypi.org/project/astral/) works for cities on the list, but not my cities.

Comment: `This works for cities on the list, but not my cities` - find city that located in the same timezone as yours.

Comment: @Alderven Just timezone is too broad; e.g. China is one huge timezone, but with vastly different celestial times.

Comment: You cite a link and say that it doesn't work because there is no package named `timezone`. But the link says: "a default datetime is used that is initialized with a LocalTimezone object from the timezone module. I have not provided that module here but you can implement one simple enough by copying the example in Python's documentation" so I think it is going a little far to say it doesn't work. You haven't really tried to make it work.

Comment: @deceze it is depends on occuracy OP needed.

Comment: @Alderven city of same time zone is not enough. The lattitude also matters.

Comment: The first reference works for some people, but I don't know how to make it work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve sunset and sunrise time from https://sunrise-sunset.org/api. 
All you need is to know your latitude and longitude. If you don't know them you can  retrieve them from `geopy` lib:

```
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

location = Nominatim().geocode('Moscow')
r = requests.get('https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json', params={'lat': location.latitude, 'lng': location.longitude}).json()['results']
print('Sunrise:', r['sunrise'])
print('Sunset:', r['sunset'])
```

Output:

```
Sunrise: 3:30:56 AM
Sunset: 3:42:58 PM
```